# VBA Unique values from 2 or more columns

Tags: excel, vba, collections, unique, multiple-columns

I would like to create a macro that can pick out unique values from a combination of 2 or more columns, and copied to another table.

For example, if i have a sample data like this:

```
Account Category
AAA USD
AAA USD
AAA CAD
BBB USD
BBB USD
```

I would hopefully get this as a result:

```
Account Category
AAA USD
AAA CAD
BBB USD
```

I've adapted this code from another thread that uses collection to find uniques for just one column. Now that I have 2 columns as a criteria, is there a way to do that?

The two columns I need compared are D and AB.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Dim LastRowInput As Long
    LastRowInput = ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim AccArr As Variant, colUnique As Collection, i As Long, ArrOut As Variant
AccArr = ws2.Range("D2:D" & LastRowInput, "AB2:AB" & LastRowInput).Value
Set colUnique = New Collection

For i = LBound(AccArr) To UBound(AccArr)
    On Error Resume Next
        colUnique.Add AccArr(i, 1), CStr(AccArr(i, 1))
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

ReDim ArrOut(1 To colUnique.Count, 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To colUnique.Count
    ArrOut(i, 1) = colUnique.Item(i)
Next i

ws1.Range("A10").Resize(UBound(ArrOut, 1), UBound(ArrOut, 2)).Value = ArrOut
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Range.RemoveDupicates`:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'realize the this is the index number and can error if the user moves the tabs around.
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Dim LastRowInput As Long
    LastRowInput = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("A10:A" & LastRowInput + 8).Value = ws2.Range("D2:D" & LastRowInput).Value
ws1.Range("B10:B" & LastRowInput + 8).Value = ws2.Range("AB2:AB" & LastRowInput).Value
ws1.Range("A10:B" & LastRowInput + 8).RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2), xlNo
```

Comment: Huh, a solution this simple never occurred to me. Thank you!

Comment: The worksheet(1) that the data pastes to will have data below it already, so this method will overwrite it before removing the dupes. I imagine I would need lock these steps in a array or variable before pasting into my desired location?

Comment: Go with @jeeped's answer it will do the removal in memory.  But if there is data below how do you know that even the unique will not overwrite?

Comment: Ahh perfect. The unique values on each instance typically don't exceed more then 4 rows. So I was looking for a faster way to pre-fill an existing template. Thank you both for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

AdvancedFilter can quickly pull out a two column unique list.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        .Range("D1:AB6").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                             CopyToRange:=.Range("AD1:AE1"), Unique:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know Scott already posted a solution, but all you have to do is this:

`Range("D1:AB6").Range("$D$1:$AB$6").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 25), Header:=xlNo`

As long as the selected range contains both columns, the array values reflect the column index.

Comment: Except that the OP wants the unique values in another sheet range and not delete the original data.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ahh I did not notice that.